# How to send data to back-end of Asp.net Project

Tags: mysql, angular, primeng, asp.net-boilerplate

I have created a simple form on the Asp.net boiler template project. I have a total of three fields
In `Table 1`

1. Product name
2. Quantity

In `Table2`

3. Tags with product List

I wanted to store third field data in another table in the database.
but I'm confused as I'm a beginner.
The product name and quantity is working fine. Can someone please guide me? Why data in the 2nd table is stored as null?

[(1) This is chips code ( from priming)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJHw.png)

[(2) This is my class code (in which all three data members exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZvVF.png)

[(3) This is my Product list class code for storing chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9iLT.png)

[(4) This is database table of Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbMTn.png)

[(5) This is Database table of Product list class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc94E.png)

[This is new attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0db6.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YMeS.png)

```
import {Component,Injector,OnInit,EventEmitter,Output,} from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';
import {
ProductServiceProxy,
ProductDto,
Product_listDto,
Product_listServiceProxy
} from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'create-product.component.html'
})
export class CreateProductComponent extends AppComponentBase
implements OnInit {
saving = false;
product = new ProductDto();

@Output() onSave = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor(
 injector: Injector,
 private _productService: ProductServiceProxy,
 public bsModalRef: BsModalRef
) {
super(injector);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

save(): void {
this.saving = true;
console.log("input",this.product)
const product = new ProductDto();
product.init(this.product);

this._productService
  .create(product)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.saving = false;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
    this.onSave.emit();
  });
}
}
```

Comment: in your chips ngModel product.productList, is it an array?

Comment: No, Can you guide me how to make it array? It it declared as list in Product class where name and quantity is also available

Comment: if you have a `product_list` list in your backend you must past a same object array from the front-end

Comment: Can you please guide me with some code sample? How can i pass list from front end?

Comment: List is simply a array

Comment: try changing your `product` class's product list to this `public List<string> ProductList {get; set:}`

Comment: Then how will i send data to backend table?

Comment: can you provide me the json object that you are sending to backend?

Comment: I've provided images, All of my code is there

Comment: no i need the final `product` object that you are passing from angular to backend

Comment: Code is long can i share somewhere else?

Comment: you can create a stack blitz and share it here...

Comment: looking at the code your are given. from angular you are passing a string array of `productList` (p-chip returns a string array). but your backend requiring a object array of `product_list` (`[ { name: "name 1"}, {name: "name2"}]`).

Comment: I've attached the code, Please guide me how to make this code correct

Comment: @AsadUllahShahid  before sending data directly from front-end(Angular ) test it with `postman`  and when you got the desired result then back to `Angular`.

Comment: console.log("input",this.product) can you give me the result of this line too

Comment: Where can i add this code?

Comment: I've attached one more Image

Comment: as you can see the name of the product list pass as `null`

Comment: Yes, What should i do? Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Your `p-chip` returns a string array but your back end requiring a object of `product_list`.you need to pass the a `product_list' object array to the backend.

> ```
> save(): void {
>     this.saving = true;
>     console.log("input",this.product)
>     let productList = [...this.product.productList];
>     this.product.productList = productList.map(item=>{
>         return {
>             Id: 0,
>             Name: item
>         }
>     });
>     const product = new ProductDto();
>     product.init(this.product);
>  }
> ```

Comment: I got this error on (this.product.productList), Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'Product_list[]'.

Comment: this.product.productList = productList.map(item=>{ name: item}); //<--- this line?

Comment: Yes, On this line

Comment: ok dont update your question regarding a answer OK. others trying to answer can get miss lead by that.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted you to see

Comment: Type '{ Name: Product_list; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product_list[]'.
  Type '{ Name: Product_list; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product_list': name, id, init, toJSON, clone

Comment: try now. i added the Id too to the object.should work now

Comment: Type '{ Id: number; Name: Product_list; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product_list[]'.
  Type '{ Id: number; Name: Product_list; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product_list': name, id, init, toJSON, clone

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me, Please fix this.

Comment: try using all small letters for name and id

Comment: Do you have a class in your angular named ` Product_list` ?

Comment: Yes there is a class, You cal also see in images above

Comment: No, Sorry there is not class in angular, I've class in visual studio

Comment: `product = new ProductDto()` comment this line and create a product object like this. product = {} as any;

Comment: Please guide me i'm beginner. I don't know much about this

Comment: you crated your product object using ProductDTO.. insted of that create it as a normal javascript object. `product = {} as any`